# Hide save/download bar on QWebEngine - PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6, qwebengine

I'm working on a PDF viewing tool using PyQt6 and QWebEngine in Python. I want to hide/remove the save and download buttons that appear when QWebEngine is running. Is this possible?

[image: ss]

Code I am currently using is as follows;

```
def preview(self):
    file_paths = [self.files_listbox.item(i).text() for i in range(self.files_listbox.count())]
    if not file_paths:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Please select a proper PDF document.')
        return

    selected_item = self.files_listbox.currentItem()
    if selected_item:
        self.preview_view.setHtml('')

        file_path = selected_item.text()
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_path)
        self.preview_view.setUrl(url)

        self.clear_preview_frame()
        self.preview_frame.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @KJ The OP probably wants to allow the user to *see* the PDF within the program, but also try to prevent printing or "downloading". Whether that may be desirable, convenient or the result unavoidable is irrelevant, the request is still reasonable.

Comment: @gilmourx Since you're using Qt6, be aware that since Qt6.4 there is a [QtPdf module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtpdf-index.html), providing a PDF API that also includes a viewer, QPdfView.